# Overwriting data in an open window.open window(Javascript)

Tags: javascript, window.open

Is there a way to reuse and overwrite data in a window.open object for Javascript? I am trying to reuse a popup window that displays information based on a selected option box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the domain of that `window.open` is the same as the origin domain opening it, yes you should be able to manipulate it as far as I know.

Comment: Do you know how to do this? The data just appends in the same window.